# Product variation WP_Query with a product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

With Woocommerce, I am trying to make a WP_Query for product variations post type with a product category 'Apple'.

```
$args = array(
    'product_cat'    => 'Apple',
    'post_type'      => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'key'            => '_visibility',
    'value'          => 'visible',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'taxonomy'       => 'pa_size',
    'meta_value'     => '39',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'         => '_stock',
            'value'       => 0,
            'compare'     => '>'
        )
    )
);
```

But I can't get it work in this query. If I remove `'product_cat' => 'Apple'`, the query works. Why?

Comment: See also for getting products without WP_Query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028830/woocommerce-get-products

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is many mistakes in this `WP_Query` regarding Woocommerce products:

- For **product category** and **product attribute** you should better use normally a `tax_query` instead.
- For **Product visibility**, since Woocommerce 3, it's handled by `product_visibility` taxonomy for `'exclude-from-search'` and `'exclude-from-catalog'` terms.

**Important notes about Product variations:**

- Product categories *(or product tags)* are **not handled** by Product variations, but by the parent Variable product
- Product attributes for variations are handled as **post meta data** with a `meta_key` prepended by "`attribute_`" and a `met_value` that is the **term slug**.
- **Product visibility is not handled in product variations**, as they are not displayed in archives pages.
- They are not displayed in archive pages (as mentioned before).

So when using a `WP_Query`, you **can NOT query** at the same time "product" post type and "product_variation" post type **as they are really different**.

To make your query work for "product_variation" post type, you need a little utility function that will get the parent variable product for a product category *(or any custom taxonomy as Product tags…)*:

```
// Utility function to get the parent variable product IDs for a any term of a taxonomy
function get_variation_parent_ids_from_term( $term, $taxonomy, $type ){
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p2 ON p2.post_parent = p.ID
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
        AND tt.taxonomy = '$taxonomy'
        AND t.$type = '$term'
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works. **Necessary for the `WP_Query` below**…

---

Here `WP_Query` code **for Product variations** *(only)* related to a specific product category and specific variation attribute values:

```
// Settings
$cat_name = 'Apple'; // Product category name
$attr_taxonomy = 'pa_size'; // Product attribute
$attribute_term_slugs = array('39'); // <== Need to be term SLUGs

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'       => 'product_variation',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'  => 100,
    'post_parent__in' => get_variation_parent_ids_from_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', 'name' ), // Variations
    'meta_query'      => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_stock',
            'value'   => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        ),
        array( 
            'key'     => 'attribute_'.$attr_taxonomy, // Product variation attribute
            'value'   => $attribute_term_slugs, // Term slugs only
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
) );

// Display the queried products count
echo '<p>Product count: ' . $query->post_count . '<p>';

// Displaying raw output for posts
print_pr($query->posts);
```

Tested and works.

Comment: @Geme I hope that this explanation will be useful for everybody…

Comment: I've been looking for an answer for more than an hour, and this is really the best one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this, you can loop products and check for if the product is `variable` and if true, you can add another loop to also include the variations, but if you must do it with `WP_Query` for any reason, you can use `posts_join` filter, when you use `tax_query` it will add a `LEFT JOIN` sql statement that will compare post `ID` column in `wp_posts` table with term relationship `object_id` column in `wp_term_relationships` table, the statement looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
```

All we need to do here is add a `OR` statement that will make the query look also for post parent ids and make the statement like below: (in Woocommerce product variations have a post parent which is the product itself)

```
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id OR wp_posts.post_parent = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
```

### Long story, short, how do we do it?

We will use a [posts_join](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_join/) filter to do this, but remember that we need to remove the filter immediately after wp_query is triggered (you can also make some unique variables and only change `join` statement if that variable is present

```
function dornaweb_include_parent_categories_join($joins, $wp_query) {
    /*
     * You can make a condition to make sure this code will only run on your intended query
     * Altough removing the filter after wp_query also do it
     */
    if ($wp_query->query['my_include_parent_posts_cat_variable']) {
        global $wpdb;
        $find = "{$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id";
        $joins = str_replace($find, $find . " OR {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_parent = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id", $joins);
    }

    return $joins;
}

add_filter( 'posts_join' , "dornaweb_include_parent_categories_join", 99, 2);

$products_list = new \WP_Query([
    'post_type'         => ['product', 'product_variation'],
    'posts_per_page'    => 15,
    'paged'             => !empty($_GET['page']) ? absint($_GET['page']) : 1,
    'tax_query'         => [
        [
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'terms'     => [$category],
        ]
    ],
    'my_include_parent_posts_cat_variable' => true
]);

remove_filter( 'posts_join' , "dornaweb_include_parent_categories_join", 99, 2);
```