# How to get only simple products and product variations (variable products excluded) based on a specific category in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to retrieve all simple products and product variations that:

- Have `post_status` equal to `publish`;
- Simple products and product variations belong to a specific product category (in my case *mobile*);

But **excluding the variable products**.

So far I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
$arg_product_filter = array(
    'nopaging'       => true,
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => array( 'product', 'product_variation' ),
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'simple', 'variation' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'mobile',
        )
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $arg_product_filter );
```

This query returned only simple products and if I change the relation to 'OR' it returns variable products as well. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following custom function to get the IDs of simple products and product variations *(**excluding variable products**)*.

Also, the function only returns products with the **publish** status by filtering them **based on the product category** specified as an argument.

The function will return an array containing the product ids.

```
/**
 * Gets the ids of simple products and product variations with the following criteria:
 * - Only if the product is published;
 * - Excludes variable products;
 * - Products belong to a specific product category.
 * 
 * @param mixed  $term     Term to search for.
 * @param string $taxonomy Taxanomy in which to search for the term.
 * @param string $type     Type of term to search for. It can contain the following values: 'term_id', 'name' or 'slug' 
 * 
 * @return array Product IDs.
 */
function get_simple_products_and_product_variations_ids_by_cat( $term, $type = 'slug', $taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr ON ( ID = tr.object_id OR post_parent = tr.object_id )
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE post_type IN ( 'product', 'product_variation' )
    AND post_status = 'publish'
    AND ID NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT post_parent AS parent_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_type = 'product_variation'
        AND post_status = 'publish'
    )
    AND tt.taxonomy = '$taxonomy'
    AND t.$type = '$term'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );

    return array_map( 'intval', $results );

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

---

**USAGE**

1. Filtering products based on **product category id** (for example `30`):

```
get_simple_products_and_product_variations_ids_by_cat( 30, 'term_id' );
```

2. Filtering products by **product category name** (for example `Red wines`):

```
get_simple_products_and_product_variations_ids_by_cat( 'Red wines', 'name' );
```

3. Filtering products based on the **product category slug** (for example `red-wines`):

```
get_simple_products_and_product_variations_ids_by_cat( 'red-wines', 'slug' );
```

---

### ANSWER

> The reason you only get simple products is that there is no relationship between product category and product variation. The only relationship is with variable product (`post_parent` of the product variation).

You can get the products by setting the [`post__in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters) parameter of the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class with the result of the custom function above, then:

```
$args = array(
    'nopaging'       => true,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => array( 'product', 'product_variation' ),
    'post__in'       => get_simple_products_and_product_variations_ids_by_cat( 'fruit' ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        global $product;

        // do stuff

    }
}
```

**RELATED ANSWERS**

- [Product variation WP_Query with a product category in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342704/product-variation-wp-query-with-a-product-category-in-woocommerce)